# Angular 6 https-proxy-agent, Denial of Service

Tags: angular6, denial-of-service, https-proxy-agent

I am using Serverless system for authentication, earlier it was working fine but then I installed jQuerya and Popper.js, as Bootstrap 4 has these dependencies [I read it somewhere]. When I installed these two then I am getting vulnerability issue with https-proxy-agent. https-proxy-agent version in my App is 2.1.1, I tried to update it to latest version as I read somewhere that in new version [2.2.0 or 2.2.1 ] it is resolved. I tried few command but I am not able to update it. 
Please suggest something on this.

Comment: serverless with aws? if yes, why not using AWS Cognito, with their SDK? It is an easy, secure, and easy solution.

Comment: I am using firebase auth service, actually before it was working fine but when I install jQuery and Popper.js (these are dependencies for Bootstrap 4) then it is showing this issue.